# Imgur API v3 - Retrieve Image/Album comments

Tags: api, imgur

I'm developing a Windows Phone unofficial client for Imgur, the documentation talks about Comments endpoints/data models...but there isn't any method to retrieve comments about a specific image or album.

Anyone known how to retrive them...if is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a month I understand how to retrieve them: just putting "/comments" after album or image id. Stupid incomplete API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify I want to add few things:

Indeed You need to put `'/comments`', so in the end Your url should look like:
`https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/cUkfS9L/comments/best`.

The id (`'cUkfS9L'` here) may be the id of IMAGE, not only gallery.

But what's more important, and where I had a problem:

It looks like this doesn't work for newest images.
I tried it for a list of newest images (got by `'(...)time/all(...)'` sorting in query) and noticed that getting comments works for like 4th page of my images.
My solution was changing `"time/all"` to `"top"`. Now I had much older images and getting comments worked well for them.